# Add class on click and remove when clicked again to that particular tr or span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i am clicking to any  it selects all the rows in the table but i want to be specific to the click.

my js is-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //appendScroll(scrollbarElement = $('.acraft-panelgroup'))
    $("#runway-select > tr").click(function() {
        // $("#runway-select ").parent('td span').removeClass("activehero");
        $("#runway-select span").parent().toggleClass("activehero");
    });
})
```

my html is -

```
<tbody id="runway-select">
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  </td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>7102<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td></td>
</tbody>
```

Please help me out if you can . I tried using Parent() but it is not working .

Comment: To which you want to add Class, please be specific

Comment: Are you want to `toggleClass("activehero");` to `td` of clicked `span`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(this).toggleClass("activehero");
```

This will toggle class on the `tr`.

```
 $(this).find('span').toggleClass("activehero");
```

This will toggle class on every `span` inside the `tr`.

`this` inside an event handler will be the current target. It is the HTML element you clicked.

`.find()` search a specified element descending from the specified target.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to toggle class `activehero` of your table columns based on the clicked row, if so then you can use:

```
$("#runway-select > tr").click(function(){ 
    $(this).find('td').toggleClass("activehero");
});
```